# How to build a nodejs application into image in argo using paketo?

Tags: command, argo-workflows, argo, paketo

I am trying to build a nodejs application into an image in awith paketo

but I am getting this error

```
Error (exit code 64): failed to find name in PATH: exec: "sh": executable file not found in $PATH
```

Here is my code

```
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Workflow
metadata:
  generateName: webhook-
spec:
  entrypoint: Build-node-with-paketo
  templates:
    - name: Build-node-with-paketo
      inputs:
        artifacts:
          - name: argo-source
            path: /ignite-nodejs
            git:
              repo: https://github.com/chuksdsilent/ignite-nodejs
      container:
        image: buildpacksio/pack:0.30.0
        command: 
          - "sh"
        args:
          - -c
          - |
            echo $(pack build my-app --buildpack paketo-buildpacks/nodejs --env BP_NODE_OPTIMIZE_MEMORY=true")
```